# JQuery's getScript equivalent in Prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Is there some equivalent to jQuery's getScript in Prototype ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var head;

var script;

head = $$('head')[0];
if (head)
{
    script = new Element('script', { type: 'text/javascript', src: 'dynamic.js' });
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Im loading this script after a user interaction, so I dont think inserting in head would execute it, would it ?
Anyway, I've used native JS to add this. Hopefully this works in all browsers.
var fileref = document.createElement('script'); fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript"); fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://domain.com/script.js");

Comment: Cool, now is there a onComplete? how can I detect when it finishes loading?

Comment: That was 2010, leave these stuff and move to Angular, Backbone etc. Also look at script loading with require.js if you just need to add script modules